# Sqlalchemy - access results of `before_update` during the transaction

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got some classes which have a version number that gets incremented on each update via a `before_update` event, roughly as follows:

```
listen(MyClass, 'before_update', increment_version)

def increment_version(mapper,connect,target):
    target.version += 1
```

I now want to store in a *different* type of object which version of a `MyClass` object operated on it.

Something like:

```
my_obj.update_some_fields() 
session.add(my_obj) # when before_update occurs, this object's version number will increment
my_other_obj.update_some_fields_based_on_my_obj()
my_other_obj.relevant_version = my_obj.version # I want this to have my_obj's new version number
session.add(my_other_obj)
```

When this session is committed, the version number on `my_obj` gets incremented, but the `relevant_version` field on `my_other_obj` is `my_obj`'s previous version number.

I need the changes to both `my_obj` and `my_other_obj` to happen within the same transaction.

How can I  access the results of `before_update` triggers within the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Use `session.flush()` during the transaction. This will ensure the callbacks get called, e.g.

```
my_obj.update_some_fields() 
session.add(my_obj) # when before_update occurs, this object's version number will increment
session.flush()
my_other_obj.update_some_fields_based_on_my_obj()
my_other_obj.relevant_version = my_obj.version # I want this to have my_obj's new version number
session.add(my_other_obj)
```

Comment: Not an ideal solution since `flush()` requires a roundtrip to the DB and could invoke db errors which would prevent control flow.

Comment: In my use case a fail at DB level that causes txn to fail is not end of the world. If you have a more efficient solution in mind then I'm happy to give it a go.